# Eclipse showing same class name automatically

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse as IDE. But when ever I create a class in java, another class with same name and same data gets created automatically. But if I delete any one of the class the other class also gets deleted.

Comment: share ur .classpath file. (u can see that in navigator view)

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the `src` source folder, and add a class, it should create only a single class. The stuff in the other folders are none of your concern, for now.

Also, please read the site guidelines and FAQ. This is different than a standard forum. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `.java` file. This gets compiled to a `.class` file with the same name. These compiled classes are by default located in a directory called `bin` which is not shown in eclipse. But you can see this in the file system. You need the `.class` files to run your application so you shouldn't delete them.